# Are com.android.ddmlib sources available via Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

While developing a plugin for Android Studio, I found I want sources for `com.android.ddmlib.*`, but they don't appear to be included in `Sources for Android 25`. Is there another source package for tools I've missed? Otherwise, where can I get the sources?

Comment: what was the plugin?

Comment: @Nazimch It's currently for our organization's internal use, but I don't see how it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are available at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/android-7.1.1_r22/ddmlib/. Unfortunately, it's not clear which tag corresponds to a specific SDK Tools version (all tags are listed at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+refs).